# How do I add a div to a page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

So... I want to add the following right before the /body of a document, I can't seem to find a way to make it work:

```
document.body.innerHTML+="<div style=\"position:absolute; right:-10px; bottom:10px;\">response</div>\"");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Especially** with the `<body>` element, you shouldn't be using `innerHTML` to append elements to an element. An easier way is with DOM methods like `createElement`, `insertBefore` or `appendChild`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild

Try this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.right = "-10px";
div.style.bottom = "10px";
div.innerHTML = "response";
var lastChild = document.body.lastChild;
document.body.insertBefore(div, lastChild.nextSibling);
```

Although I guess it would make sense to just append it to the `body`:

```
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

(instead of the last two lines in my first example)

It also depends on when you're calling this code. Of course it will work if executed in the middle of the `<body>`, but you probably want to wait until the body (DOM) is ready so that the element is actually appended at the *real* end of the body. By using something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Your code from above
};
```

This will make sure the original `<body>` contents are ready.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add stuff like that! Instead, do this:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div')
newDiv.style.position = 'absolute'
newDiv.id = 'myDiv'
newDiv.innerHTML = 'hello'
//etc.
document.body.appendChild(newDiv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code to

```
document.body.innerHTML="<div style=\"position:absolute; right:-10px; bottom:10px;\">response</div>\"";
```

Remove ) at the end

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

// it's better use a CSS here instead
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.right = "-10px";
div.style.bottom = "10px";

div.innerHTML = "response";

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

?